# Odd exception behavior in Inno script when CurPageChanged is declared

Tags: exception, inno-setup

In the below script, an AfterInstall procedure (SetupOperation) executes after the installation of the lone file installed.  If it fails, I want to abort setup, which I do by calling WizardForm.Close.  The problem is, if the CurPageChanged procedure is merely declared, the the exception is never properly rethrown in SetupOperation.  If I comment it out, everything works properly.  There's got to be something simple I'm missing.

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
AppID=someuniqueid
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyCompany\ExampleApp
SetupLogging=yes
AppName=ExampleApp
AppVersion=1.2.3.4
AppVerName=ExampleApp 1.2.3.4
AppPublisher=MyCompany
OutputBaseFilename=MyCompany.ExampleApp.1234

[Files]
Source: "d:\temp\test.txt"; DestDir: "{commonappdata}\MyCompany\ExampleApp"; AfterInstall: SetupOperation

[Code]
var SharedProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;

// Called by Inno to initialize the user interface
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    Log('InitializeWizard called');

    SharedProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('Installing', 'Please wait while Setup installs the ExampleApp on your computer.');
    SharedProgressPage.SetProgress(0,1);
    SharedProgressPage.ProgressBar.Style := npbstMarquee;
end;

// Called when the current wizard page changes
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin

end;

procedure SetupOperation();
begin
    Log('SetupOperation called');

    try
        SharedProgressPage.SetText('', '');
        SharedProgressPage.Show;

        try
            SharedProgressPage.SetText('Performing operation...', '');
            RaiseException('Some weird error');
        except
            Log('Caught an exception; re-raising');
            RaiseException(GetExceptionMessage());
        finally
            Log('Closing progress page');
            SharedProgressPage.Hide;
        end;
    except
        Log('An error occurred setting performing the operation: ' + GetExceptionMessage());
        WizardForm.Close();
    end;
end;
```

This might have something to do with the usage of a TOutputProgressWizardPage, but I don't see how.  It seems to get shown/hidden properly.

Comment: What exception is *"not rethrown"*?

Comment: In the except block I "RaiseException(GetExceptionMessage())" - essentially a rethrow.  If CurPageChanged is not present, the outer except block catches it and closes the wizard.  When present, the outer except block is seemingly bypassed - nothing is logged, and the wizard is not closed, and the install completes successfully.

Comment: OK, It indeed looks like a bug in Inno Setup. I do not think there's anything wrong in your code. You would have to workaround it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Martin.  I just dropped the nested try blocks and it gets me around the issue.